# Launching flutter app on my physical iPhone via xcode set in portrait mode works, but not when launching through android studio

Tags: android, ios, xcode, flutter

In my main.dart file where I have declared the device orientation

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() { SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
  runApp(Egenkontroll());
}
```

When I launch the app through xcode on my physical iPhone 7, I get my views in portrait mode which I want, but when I launch in through android studio on my device portrait mode is not enabled, and the views adjust to the devices orientation, which I don't want.

Does this matter when I publish the app on the appstore?

Answer (score 0):

`SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations` is async task so either await or put your run inside then

```
 SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp])
      .then((_) =>
      runApp(Egenkontroll())
      );
```

OR

```
await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
runApp(Egenkontroll());
```